# sql mod with value = 0

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT id, MOD(MID(ssn,12,1),2) FROM `table`
```

This is the query I'm using. It's working fine, however when:

```
MID(ssn,12,1)
```

is 0, it will return 0. (Don't know if this is correct or not, but it's not my question.) I need it to return 1. Row 10 and 11 should be listed as 1.
fyi, the ssn numbers are fake. and it wouldnt be a problem. my country has them listed publicly. dont need to mention it

[image]

Could anyone help me? I'm stuck.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKXKU.png

Comment: Bad idea of sharing SSN numbers in a public forum..unless the provided data is fake.

Comment: they're fake, and it wouldnt be a problem. because ssn numbers are publicly available in my country

Comment: You can't change the fact that MOD(0, 2) is 0...

Comment: I think you should explain **what you need to get** instead of searching for _workarounds_ for modulus...

Comment: why you "need to get 1" ? The result seems to conform to what you asked the db to do. What is the logic behind, as Adriano asks ?

Comment: i dont know the logic. 1,3,5,7,9,0 represents a female, 2,4,6,8 is a male. and i need to find out which sex they are using the numbers represented and figured that odd/even would be the easiest way to find it

Comment: odds can represent females only if you say 0 represents a male (and not a female, as you state). And which digit from the ssn value is the one relevant for this check ? the 12th ? always ?

Comment: the 12th number always tells which gender you are, all odds and 0 is a female. the even ones are male

Comment: I don't believe that 0 is for females, it's even and should denote a male. However, @Rahul's solution would give you the wanted result if you'd like to convert 0's to 1's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result which you are getting seems to be correct as:

```
MID(str, pos, len)
```

> pos: An integer indicating the position (within the str) from where
>   extraction should start.

So in case of 10 row which

```
1  9  4  6  0  2  2  0  -  8   1   0   2
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
                                   ^^
```

So the 12th element is 0 and hence the result.

You cannot change the functionality of MOD function. However if you want to return it as 1 instead of the 0 which you are getting then you can try it like this:

```
SELECT id, case when MID(ssn,12,1) = 0 then 'female'  
                when mod(MID(ssn,12,1),2)=1 then 'female' else 'male' 
           end
FROM `table`
```

Comment: "(Don't know if this is correct or not, but it's not my question.)" but thanks for clarifying it

Comment: @user5288040:- Updated my answer and added some more details!

Comment: thank you, ive marked your answer as the answer. i used what you included to do my own. so thanks!